# How do I find more comprehensive Google Documentation for using its APIs

Tags: github, google-api

A lot of the times the Google documentation is incomplete and is missing things like libraries required to import. How do I view a more comprehensive example?

Example: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces#vision-face-detection-python

```
def highlight_faces(image, faces, output_filename):

    """Draws a polygon around the faces, then saves to output_filename.

    Args:
      image: a file containing the image with the faces.
      faces: a list of faces found in the file. This should be in the format
          returned by the Vision API.
      output_filename: the name of the image file to be created, where the
          faces have polygons drawn around them.
    """

    im = Image.open(image)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    for face in faces:
        box = [(vertex.x, vertex.y)
               for vertex in face.bounding_poly.vertices]
        draw.line(box + [box[0]], width=5, fill='#00ff00')

    im.save(output_filename)
```

Missing the `PIL` import

Answer (score 1):

On many of Google's code examples, there will be a `VIEW ON GITHUB` button that will take you to a complete working example rather than a snippet. Very useful for finding necessary library imports or just going straight to more code.

[image]

When that is missing, sometimes there is a link to the file like this firebase example linking to `index.js`:

[image]